# Why is Jasmine not executing it() on this async test?

Tags: javascript, tdd, jasmine

I'm trying to test a prototypal method that returns insights about a dataset I am loading via AJAX.

```
$.getJSON('../data/bryce.json').done(function(data) {

    insights = new Insights(data);

    describe("People Method", function() {

       console.log('it executes this far');

        it("should return complete people data", function() {

            console.log('but not this far');

            expect(insights.people()).toBeTruthy();

        });

    });

});
```

When I run this test suite, describe() executes, but not it(). I'm pretty new to JavaScript testing in general, so I imagine I'm doing something wrong. But I'm not sure what it is.

Also, because the data I'm working with is a *huge* JSON file, it's not really possible to include it in this file. Nor would it be possible to even provide a sample-size version. Each object in the dataset is hundreds of lines long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasmine works off a queuing mechanism and executes all the `describe` and `it` functions queuing up work to be executed.

Doing work asyncronously in Jasmine requires you to follow a certain pattern.

**Jasmine 1.x**

```
describe('some suite', function(){

  it('some test', function(){

     var data;

     //Execute some async operation
     runs(function(){
         $.get('myurl').done(function(d){ data = d; });
     });

     //Wait for it to finish
     waitsFor(function(){
        return typeof data !== 'undefined';
     });

     //Assert once finished
     runs(function(){
        expect(data.foo).toBe('bar');
     });

  });

});
```

Jasmine 1.x uses a special polling mechanism to keep polling the `waitsFor` method until it times out, or returns true, and then executes the final `runs` method.

**Jasmine 2.x**

```
describe('some suite', function(){

  var data;

  beforeEach(function(done){
     $.get('myurl').done(function(d){ 
        data = d;

        //Signal test to start
        done();
     });
  });

  it('some test', function(done){
     expect(data.foo).toBe('bar');

     //Signal test is finished
     done();
  });

});
```

Jasmine 2.x is a bit different, as it uses a signaling mechanism to indicate when to start and finish the test. Your specs can take in an optional `done` method to use for synchronizing your tests.

If you use the `done` method in `beforeEach` then it will not start your test until that method is called.

If you use the `done` method in your `it` function, then the test will not finish until that method has been called.

Both of these can be used to effectively manage asynchronous behavior within your tests.