# Async with callback testing with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, jasmine, browserify

I'm trying to test a module (uses browserify to bundle) that does a XMLHttpRequest. The module looks like:

```
module.exports = function(year, cb) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', encodeURI('data/' + year + '.json'));
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var counties = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      cb(counties);
    } else {
      cb(xhr.status);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};
```

My Jasmine test looks like:

```
var counties = require('myModule');

describe('did ajax call respond', function() {
  var countyList;

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    counties(2015, function(data) {
      countyList = data;
    });
    done();
  });

  it('should return', function(done) {
    console.log(countyList);
    expect(countyList).not.toEqual({});
    expect(countyList).not.toBeUndefined();
    done();
  });
});
```

I've seen this question - [Why is Jasmine not executing it() on this async test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088884/why-is-jasmine-not-executing-it-on-this-async-test) - which seems to be the exact same thing but it's still not working.

I'm getting `undefined` for `countyList`. My jasmine output is:

```
did ajax call respond
    X should return
        Expected undefined not to be undefined. (1)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `done()` is in the wrong place. It must be inside the callback function passed to `counties`:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  counties(2015, function(data) {
    countyList = data;
    done();
  });
});
```

This will ensure that the `it` methods will only be called after `done` is executed, so, after `data` has returned, and you already have your `countyList` populated.

Comment: So that got me closer, thanks. But now the error is:
`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL. (1)` I thought that wouldn't happen with this solution. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to set this variable in the begining? probably, the `xhr` is taking more time than what Jasmine waits for it. You could, for example, try to set it to `10000` before the `beforeEach`/`it` calls. But, much better than that: you could use ES7's `async/await` and then transpile them through Babel.

Comment: Sorry @Buzinas, not sure what you mean by ...
"have you tried to set this variable in the begining? probably, the xhr is taking more time than what Jasmine waits for it. You could, for example, try to set it to 10000 before the beforeEach/it calls."

Comment: @awolfe76 e.g: `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000; beforeEach(function(done) { /* (...) */ }); it('should (...)', function(done) { /* (...) */ });`, gotcha?

Comment: You can pass a second parameter to beforeEach that sets the timeout.  e.g.  beforeEach(function(){ // do something }. 3000);